# Presto SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, presto

Let's assume that i have an array of strings with the following values:

```
string = {'123','12ab','38','abc','01a8','1123b'}
```

how should i do a query in Presto SQL to extract only the values containing only and only numerical digits, so that my output would be {'123','38'}?

doing something like the query below, does not returns any output

```sql
SELECT string
FROM table1
WHERE string LIKE '[0-9]*'
GROUP BY string
```

example of my data sample
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1AVg.png)

Comment: `string = {'123','12ab','38','abc','01a8','1123b'}` does not look like array to me. Do you have json array in data? Can you please post some actual examples, i.e. few rows from `select string from table1`?

Comment: sorry, that's only an example.. so i'm retriving data from a variable to a column... imagine that column has the following values

COLUMN1
123
12ab
38
abc
01a8
1123b

so my question is:
if i want to get the values from COLUMN1 that only contains numerical digits, how can i do that in presto sql query? is that even possible?

Comment: i've updated my question with a picture of my data

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options:

1. leverage [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html?#try_cast) operator provided by Presto

   ```sql
   -- sample data
   WITH dataset(string) AS (
     values ('123'),
            ('12ab'),
            ('38'),
            ('abc'),
            ('01a8'),
            ('1123b')
    )

    -- query
    select *
    from dataset
    where try_cast(string as integer) is not null;
   ```

Or use regular expressions via [`regexp_like`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?#regexp_like):

```sql
 -- query
 select *
 from dataset
 where regexp_like(string, '^\d+$');
```

Output:

| string |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 38 |

Comment: this approach worked for me, many thanks!

Comment: @NunoMiguelOliveiraMilhomens was glad to help! If answer worked for you please mark it as accepted one(checkmark on the left)